# Cordova build ANDROID_HOME

Tags: android, bash, cordova, home-directory

I'm trying to create a Cordova project. I have a problem when I try this command from shell: "sudo cordova build". Return error message is:

```
francesco@francesco:~/hello$ sudo cordova build

Running command: /home/francesco/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/francesco/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/francesco/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

My .bashrc file is this:

```
 # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
    # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
    # for examples

    # If not running interactively, don't do anything
    case $- in
        *i*) ;;
          *) return;;
    esac

    # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
    # See bash(1) for more options
    HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

    # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
    shopt -s histappend

    # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
    HISTSIZE=1000
    HISTFILESIZE=2000

    # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
    # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
    shopt -s checkwinsize

    # If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
    # match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
    #shopt -s globstar

    # make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
    [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

    # set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
    if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
        debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
    fi

    # set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
    case "$TERM" in
        xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
    esac

    # uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
    # off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
    # should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
    #force_color_prompt=yes

    if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
        if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
        else
        color_prompt=
        fi
    fi

    if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    fi
    unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

    # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
    case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac

    # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
    if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
        test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
        alias ls='ls --color=auto'
        #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
        #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

        alias grep='grep --color=auto'
        alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
        alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
    fi

    # some more ls aliases
    alias ll='ls -alF'
    alias la='ls -A'
    alias l='ls -CF'

    # Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
    #   sleep 10; alert
    alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

    # Alias definitions.
    # You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
    # ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
    # See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

    if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
        . ~/.bash_aliases
    fi

    # enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
    # this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
    # sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
    if ! shopt -oq posix; then
      if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
      elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
        . /etc/bash_completion
      fi
    fi

    export HOME="/home/francesco"
    export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-sdk-linux"
    export PATH="$HOME/android-sdk-linux/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms:$PATH"
```

How can I set ANDROID_HOME and "android" command?

My android-sdk is located in "home/francesco/android-sdk-linux"

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms` should be `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Comment: Thanks. Now the problem this is: [apkbuilder] Errore keytool: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/francesco/.android/debug.keystore (Permesso negato)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related with your `.bashrc` file.

Solution? Create .bash_profile inside you home directory.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/francesco/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/francesco/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the problem this is: [apkbuilder] Errore keytool: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/francesco/.android/debug.keystore (Permesso negato)

Comment: you need to create your own keystore.

Answer (score 0):

you must to set the root path of android sdk into an environment variable.
In your case:
  export ANDROID_HOME=/home/francesco/android-sdk-linux

Comment: Nothing. The same problem.  "export ANDROID_HOME=/home/francesco/android-sdk-linux" must paste in .bashrc file?

Comment: Thanks. Now the problem this is: [apkbuilder] Errore keytool: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/francesco/.android/debug.keystore (Permesso negato)

Comment: Try to delete the hidden folder _.android_ in your home folder, and try again

Answer (score 0):

Use NANO editor to save your path in .bash or .profile or .bash_profile depending on your OS.

I have a mac and face similar issue.

Check below URL on how to use NANO to edit and save file

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/

http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.html

http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.html

Put your path in desired file and it will work and you will not required to export path every time you open terminal.

Comment: Now the problem this is: [apkbuilder] Errore keytool: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/francesco/.android/debug.keystore (Permesso negato)

Comment: You need to create application signing key and provide its path as keystore to Cordova to create a release build. Please go through android documentation to know how to create keystore using terminal and Cordova documentation to know how and where to pass the path.

Comment: Debug built don't require any key

Comment: False @AbhinavTyagi : see [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) under _Signing in Debug Mode_

Comment: I have never used signing key for testing and debugging unless I am putting the apk on play store !!